# SQL batch separators in various DBMSes

Tags: sql, cross-platform

I'm continuing my quest on creating a [database migration framework](http://code.google.com/p/octalforty-wizardby/), and I'm currently trying to implement proper support for native (platform-dependent) SQL scripts.

From a SQL Server standpoint I know that a single `.sql` may contain several batches of SQL separated by `GO` terminators. `GO` itself is not a valid T-SQL keyword/whatever and is used purely to separate batches.

What I want to know is this: what keywords/identifiers/etc. are used to separate batches in other DBMSes, like SQLite, Oracle, etc., if any.

**EDIT**
In SQL Server, batches are used both to group and to separate statements. For example, `CREATE SCHEMA` statement should be the first statement in a batch, so it should be preceded by the `GO` keyword/identifier. I assume other systems have same concepts.

Comment: since this question doesn't really have a single answer, it's probably best as a community wiki

Answer (score 2):

PL/SQL (Oracle) uses `/`

Answer (score 1):

If by 'Batch' you mean a single file containing more than one SQL "statement" (e.g. a group of insert or update statements) then you can use a ; to separate them in MySQL